# What is the meaning of this file status?

Tags: version-control, visual-sourcesafe

I'm working with Visual source safe 6.0 and in the explorer I can see all the files with status (checked out or not)

For the "checked out" files I just noticed that there are two different icons:

[image: screenshot]

I just wonder what is the difference between these two statuses.

I already had the two icons without doing something particular..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found it.

It seems the second icon (the one with 3 little files) is for checked out files shared with multiple projects..

visible in the properties of the file..